# Installing & using the asbio package under OS X

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I'm a TA in a statistics class, and the students are supposed to use the "asbio" package in r for multiple comparisons. Some of those who have OSX are complaining that asbio will not load. I cannot reproduce the error on my own mac.

Here are the errors one of the students is seeing:

```
>library(asbio)
Loading required package: tcltk
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10):   Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘tcltk’ could not be loaded
> install.packages("tcltk")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Here are a few things students have tried:

- install tcltk2: "It works now, but I still get errors" (Sorry, I know that's a confusing answer, but it's what I have)
- install xquartz: "Now it works."

I suspect that xquartz is the right answer here, but if anybody could explain what's going on and confirm, that would be awesome.

(And why the *^*& would a numerical statistics package need tcl/tk anyway???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tcl/tk needs an X11 environment to work in for graphical output and Apple no longer ships an X11 environment with their operating system. XQuartz fills that gap, but is a separate install. Said install makes the X11 libraries available (look at the missing libraries in your errors) and those libraries—in turn—make graphical operations with tcl/tk possible.

the `absio` package has functions that let you do animation (like [anim.ci](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/asbio/functions/anm.ci)) which rely on the graphics capabilities of tcl/tk.

Comment: So the answer is: install xquartz. And then, at least for some of my students, restarting the machine seemed to help, too. (I'm not 100% sure that the restart was really what made the difference, because I never saw it personally.)

Answer (score 0):

A student in the class posted the following instructions:

1) Install xquartz.  You don't need to click it ever again after installing it.

2) Restart computer.

3) Open Rstudio (or whatever R).  Run library(tcltk).  Don't use require or install.packages for it.  Computer should now open up xquartz on its own.

4) Run install.packages("asbio")

5) library(asbio)

6) You should be able to run pairw.anova.

(I'm still waiting to see if the student wants credit by name here, but in any case, I'm thankful to them.)